# rsyslog forward a logfile to elasticsearch

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, rsyslog

I'm having difficulties, getting a very basic rsyslog action to work. I'd like it to grab a file and forward it using the elasticsearch module. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to bind the input with an action through ruleset.

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
module(load="omelasticsearch")

template(name="logstash-index"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="logstash-")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="1" position.to="4")
    constant(value=".")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="6" position.to="7")
    constant(value=".")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339" position.from="9" position.to="10")
}

template(name="plain-syslog"
  type="list") {
    constant(value="{")
      constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
      constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")        property(name="hostname")
      constant(value="\",\"severity\":\"")    property(name="syslogseverity-text")
      constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
      constant(value="\",\"tag\":\"")   property(name="syslogtag" format="json")
      constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")    property(name="msg" format="json")
    constant(value="\"}")
}

ruleset (name="somename") {
action(type="omelasticsearch"
    template="plain-syslog"
    searchIndex="logstash-index"
    server="10.10.10.5"
    serverport="9200"
    bulkmode="on"
    queue.type="linkedlist"
    queue.size="5000"
    queue.dequeuebatchsize="300"
    action.resumeretrycount="-1"
    dynSearchIndex="on")
}

input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/haproxy.log"
      Tag="haproxy"
      StateFile="state-haproxy"
      Severity="notice"
      escapelf="on"
      readMode="2"
      Facility="local7"
      ruleset="somename")
```

Can someone knowledgeable fix my code attempt (and maybe show an example of forwarding multiple files at the same time?)

PS. One way i got it to work, is directing a service (haproxy) to log to local7 (for example) and then binding rsyslog action to local7.*, but thats only a temporary workaround as i need to be able to forward files...